# What is the flux $\Phi$ enclosed by cyclotron orbit, which can express the quantization rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrons, discrete, quantization

Suppose an electron (mass $m$, charge $e$) in the xy-plane with $B=(0,0,B)$ (The classical EOM result in circular orbit). Using the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization rule we can find that $E_n = (n+1/2)\hbar\omega_c$ where $\omega_c=eB/m$ - the cyclotron frequency.

The next exercise asks me to show that the quantization rule can also be expressed in terms of the flux $\Phi$ enclosed by the cyclotron orbit: $\Phi_n = (n+1/2)h/e$.

The solutions say the following: $p_x=eBy$ gives $\oint p_x dx = eB\oint ydx = e\Phi$.

The only step I don't understand is the equality $B\oint ydx = \Phi$. How exactly is this flux (which has units of $JA^{-1}$) defined?

If I just assume this step, it is no problem for me to get to the expression $\Phi_n = (n+1/2)h/e$, although I don't really understand what it means.

Comment: This follows in one step by [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem).

Comment: Green shows that $\oint y dx$ equals the area enclosed by the orbit, right? Then still I don't understand why $B\oint y dx$ is a flux

Comment: Here, the flux is the magnetic field times the area.

Comment: Why? What kind of flux is this?

Comment: It's the same "flux" you encountered in a high school course in electromagnetism. For example, Faraday's law is $\mathcal{E} = - d \Phi / dt$.

Comment: Ohhh It's just the magnetic flux. I now see that I failed at deriving the units of the flux, convincing me that I was dealing with some other quantity. Thanks :)

Comment: Using Green's theorem, shouldn't we get a minus sign? I mean that $\oint ydx = \iint 0-\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} dxdy$?

Answer (score 0):

The flux we're dealing with is the [magnetic flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux). It is in this case just the magnetic field times the area.

By [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) we find that the integral indeed is equal to the area.